# What is the name of a self-repeating/looping/rotating matrix?

Tags: matrices, terminology

I have a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. What's special about this matrix is that the leftmost column and rightmost column are adjacent. i.e. `M[0,0]` is considered as a neighbor of with `M[0,n-1]`.

What is the name of this ring-shape self-repeating/looping matrix/ data structure, if there is one?

Comment: For $m=0$ you might want to look up circular array/circular buffer/ring buffer

Comment: What does it mean, to consider one column as a neighbor of another? What practical effect does that have?

Comment: What @Ben proposed is exactly what I want. I am wondering if there is a name for a similar representation in math.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well, the adjacency might impact results of connectivity-related operations, such as convolution.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Not really. That matrix just has rotating columns and has nothing to do with connectivity.

Comment: If the top and bottom rows are also adjacent, this is called a *toroidal matrix* or *toroidal array*.